# Rearranging lists and dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with a large number of data.frames (d=100) each containing a number of variables (v=10). I would like to rearrange the data so that I instead have a new list of 10 data.frames with 100 columns each, extracting the relevant column from each of the 100 original data.frames. So new data.frame1 will have 100 columns each being the 1st column from original data.frames, new data.frame2 will have 100 columns each being the 2nd column from original data.frames,....,n . What's the best way to rearrange this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi wit and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way, using dummy data, as you didn't provide input.

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- df5 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:3, v2 = 4:6)
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df"))
```

I assume your list looks something like `lst` above. Here we have 5 data frames with 2 columns each and we rearrange it such that we end up with a list of 2 data frame containing 5 columns each.

```
split_idx <- seq_len(unique(lengths(lst))) # in your case, this should give you 1:10
out <- split.default(x = Reduce(cbind, lst), split_idx)
#$`1`
#  v1 v1.1 v1.2 v1.3 v1.4
#1  1    1    1    1    1
#2  2    2    2    2    2
#3  3    3    3    3    3

#$`2`
#  v2 v2.1 v2.2 v2.3 v2.4
#1  4    4    4    4    4
#2  5    5    5    5    5
#3  6    6    6    6    6
```

`split.default` splits a list along columns.

---

If we need to change the names of each data frame we might do

```
out <- lapply(out, function(x) {
  names(x) <- paste0(gsub("(v[0-9]+)\\.+", "\\1", names(x)), "_", 1:5)
  x
  })

out
#$`1`
#  v1_1 v1_2 v1_3 v1_4 v1_5
#1    1    1    1    1    1
#2    2    2    2    2    2
#3    3    3    3    3    3

#$`2`
#  v2_1 v2_2 v2_3 v2_4 v2_5
#1    4    4    4    4    4
#2    5    5    5    5    5
#3    6    6    6    6    6
```

Comment: It works perfectly, exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you. A very small question, not important to the outcome but is there a way to reference the column names in 'out' starting with v1.1 and v2.1 respectively rather than the 2nd column being v1.1 and v2.1 respectively, ... with the last column of 100 being v1.100 and v2.100 rather than v1.99 and v2.99?